# Returning a value under if statement for Python 2.7

Tags: python, if-statement, return, factorial

I am trying to calculate factorial of a number. If the user enters a negative number, I want the loop to rerun. However, when I use the return function under if statement for negative values, it gives me an error of

```
"SyntaxError: 'return' outside function"
```

How can I rerun the loop if the user enters a negative number.

```
# Calculating the Factorial of a Number

number = input ("Please enter a positive number: ")
factorial = 1

if number > 0:
    for n in range (1, number):
        factorial = factorial * (n+1)
        print ("You entered the number of " + str(number) + ". The factorial of that number is " + str (factorial))
else:
    number = input ("You entered a negative number. Please enter a positive number: ")
    return number
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a `return` statement outside of a function.

> > How can I rerun the loop if the user enters a negative number?

Use a while loop:

```
number = -1
while number < 0:
    try:
        # since factorial applies to integers only
        number = int(input("Please enter a positive number: "))
    except ValueError: # so we don't crash if the user enters a string or a float
        pass
# here number is guaranteed to be a positive integer
factorial = 1
for n in range (1, number):
    factorial = factorial * (n+1)
print 'The factorial of {number} is {factorial}'.format(number=number,
                                                        factorial=factorial)
```

Comment: First of all thank you. But when you say number = -1, you are stating the number which is supposed to be determined by the user. I did not get it clearly, how rest of code goes here. Because, in this case the program will go into while number < 0, since you assigned number = -1 .  Sorry I am a beginner in Python. So I did not get it. Thanks.

Comment: I have set `number` to `-1` so we get into the `while` loop. Inside that we get the user input, turn it to an integer and then re-assigning it to `number.` If it's happen to be a negative integer we enter the `while` loop again.

Comment: Right now, I got it. Thank you for clarifying.